# Why Azure ASP (App Service Plan) manual scale-up is too slow?

Tags: azure, web-services, cloud, scale

Currently, I have an Azure ASP I1, which contains about 8 app services and 2 function apps.
When I do the manual scale-out from 1 instance to 2 instances. it costs about more than 30 minutes and I think it is too slow.
My questions:

1. What reasons are effecting to the scale time? (number of resources, apps?)
2. What can I do to reduce the manual scale time? ( I mean the best practice of configuration)
3. If we apply auto-scale to this ASP, will it scale faster? If not, the auto-scale will not bring any value, because when the moment that the scale is finished, the pressure to our server might already be reduced.

Any partial answer and discussion will be appreciated

Comment: Could this be the answer of your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598439/how-long-does-it-take-for-an-azure-app-service-instance-to-be-available-after-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding with scaling is that it is a simple sum total of how long it would take to provision all the resources that come under the service plan. You said, you have 8 app services and 2 function apps. Try to think back to how long it took to provision them. If each app took about a minute, then, it would be roughly 10 minutes. for example, if your app has a cosmos db, that along would take anywhere from 3 to 10 minutes. i am speaking based on my own experience.

So, now, to your questions.

- What reasons are effecting to the scale time? (number of resources, apps?)

Yes individual apps and the resources they depend on are a huge factor in deciding the scale time.

- What can I do to reduce the manual scale time? ( I mean the best practice of configuration)

not much. this is one of those that is outside your control.

However, if I were you, I would consider moving some of the apps and functions out of this service plan, and may be manage them individually?

Let's say I have a web app with a database service. I find out that the server is able to handle the load just fine, but it is the database that needs a bigger plan. Then, instead of keeping them on the same plan, i would move the database to a separate plan, only focus the scaling efforts on the database and leave the web app service alone.

- If we apply auto-scale to this ASP, will it scale faster?

No.